# AMPscript not woring in email body

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, email-template

This maybe a silly question as i am totally unknown to the AMPscript.

I am trying to get date in the email body so wrote the following code, but when sent out test emails, the code was not replaced by the date. Please help.

%%=Format(Now(), "MMMM d, yyyy")=%%

Please confirm if the code is right and does this needs to be placed in some special tag or it can be put anywhere in the body

Comment: Did you wrote it in HTML / Codeblocks or in the text editor? If you have used the text editor this might be the reason why this fails. Copy that stuff to the HTML / codeblock.

Comment: I copied in the html editor inside the body tag only and saved .

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test from my side and the AMPScript code works properly. The date looks like 'February 20, 2019'.